# foreach on UTF8 array

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8, foreach

I'm seeing something odd!

See, here is my array:

```
$array = array('حساب داری', 'صنایع', 'مهندسی سخت افزار', 'مهندسی عمران');

print_r($array):

Array
(
    [0] => حساب داری
    [1] => صنایع
    [2] => مهندسی سخت افزار
    [3] => مهندسی عمران
)
```

The values of the above array contains utf-8 characters, now the foreach:

```
    $test = '';
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $test.= " ('1', '$value'), ";   
    }
```

The output is:

```
('1', 'حساب داری'),  ('1', 'صنایع'),  ('1', 'مهندسی سخت افزار'),  ('1', 'مهندسی عمران'),
```

As you see it's all wrong... .

why is this happening and how I would fix this?

Thanks in advance

P.S: using some utf-8 decode functions are not working.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with right to left text.

Comment: try using `$test .= sprintf("('%d', '%s')",$key,$value)`

Comment: @wumm nope, see the first parenthesis, it has 3

Comment: @Ethan `('0', 'حساب داری')('1', 'صنایع')('2', 'مهندسی سخت افزار')('3', 'مهندسی عمران')`

Comment: Colon after `print_r` instead of semi-colon?

Comment: @CD001 it's just the way of showing you that it's the results of the print_r, I have no errors in my php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beginning of the string is interpreted as left-to-right, and the rest as right-to-left. You can solve the glitch by setting the whole document to right-to-left:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

If you want the document to be shown as primarily left-to-right you'll have to add some control characters after each Arabic string to force a change to LTR since digits and punctuation are not "strong" enough. If your output contained LTR letters (like A) it would also be rendered as expected; test these:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $test.= " ('1', '$value&lrm;'), ";   
}

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $test.= " ('A', '$value'), ";   
}
```